# Boundary velocity of moving surface in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: calculus, surfaces, leibniz-integral-rule

Let's have a surface $\Sigma(t)$ moving in the three-dimensional space $\mathbb{R}^3$, with boundary $\partial \Sigma$ as in the below figure:

[sketch-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTELA.png)

Let's have a space-dependent scalar $c(\mathbf{x})$, with $\mathbf{x}$ the three-dimensional position vector.

I use the Leibniz rule to compute:

$$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} \int_{\Sigma(t)} c(\mathbf{x}) \mathrm{d} \Sigma = \int_{\Sigma(t)} \dfrac{\partial c(\mathbf{x})}{\partial t} \mathrm{d} \Sigma + \int_{\partial\Sigma} (c \mathbf{v}_b) \cdot \mathbf{n} \ \mathrm{d} s$$

The second term is null because the scalar field $c$ is fixed in time.
If also the boundary $\partial \Sigma$ is fixed $\mathbf{v}_b=0$ and:

$$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} \int_{\Sigma(t)} c(\mathbf{x}) \mathrm{d} \Sigma = 0 \ ,$$

which is clearly not the case for my expanding moving surface.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: Where are you getting this formula from?

Comment: @KevinS https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: I see the problem. Your formula works when $\partial\Sigma$ is a 2-dimensional surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and $\Sigma$ is a 3-dimensional region. This formula is used to derive all kind of conservation laws in Fluid Mechanics, Thermodynamics, etc. There, $n$ is the normal to the surface.

Comment: Yes with volumes included by closed surfaces I see no problem. As well as R2 plane problems. But shouldn t that work also for other dimensionalities?

Comment: No. The issue is that when $\Sigma$ is a $3$-dimensional region in $\Bbb R^3$, the only way it can move with time is for its boundary to move as a function of time. When you have a surface in $\Bbb R^3$, it can certainly deform (as you're discovering) in time, even keeping its boundary fixed.

Comment: I agree that is the deformation the problem. Then, as I realised, the typical transport theorem (or Leibniz rule for integral) in the above formulation is ill-posed (see my comment below also)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing your expression with the *"Three-dimensional, time-dependent case"* on wiki (resp.):
$$\color{blue}{\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\Sigma(t)}c(\boldsymbol{x})d\Sigma = \int_{\Sigma(t)}\frac{\partial c(\boldsymbol{x})}{\partial t}d\Sigma + \int_{\partial\Sigma}(c\boldsymbol{v}_b)\cdot \boldsymbol{n}ds}$$
$$\text{vs.}$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int\int_{\Sigma(t)}\boldsymbol{F}(\boldsymbol{r},t)\cdot d\boldsymbol{A}=\int\int_{\Sigma(t)}(\boldsymbol{F}_t(\boldsymbol{r},t)+[\nabla\cdot\boldsymbol{F}(\boldsymbol{r},t)]\boldsymbol{v})\cdot d\boldsymbol{A}-\oint_{\partial\Sigma(t)}[\boldsymbol{v}\times\boldsymbol{F}(\boldsymbol{r},t)]\cdot d\boldsymbol{s}$$

---

It seems we should have:
$$\color{red}{\boldsymbol{F}(\boldsymbol{r},t)}:= c(\boldsymbol{x}),\text{ }\text{ }\color{red}{d\boldsymbol{{A}}}:=\boldsymbol{n}(\boldsymbol{x})d\Sigma, \text{ }\text{ and }\text{ }\text{ }\color{red}{d\boldsymbol{s}}:=\boldsymbol{n}(\boldsymbol{x})ds$$
with
$$(\boldsymbol{F}_t(\boldsymbol{r},t)+[\nabla\cdot \boldsymbol{F}(\boldsymbol{r},t)]\boldsymbol{v})\cdot d\boldsymbol{A} = \color{blue}{\frac{\partial c(\boldsymbol{x})}{\partial t}\boldsymbol{n}(\boldsymbol{x})d\Sigma}\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }(\star1)$$ and $$-[\boldsymbol{v}\times \boldsymbol{F}(\boldsymbol{r},t)]\cdot d\boldsymbol{s}= \color{blue}{(c(\boldsymbol{x})\boldsymbol{v}_b)\cdot \boldsymbol{n}(\boldsymbol{x})ds}.\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }(\star2)$$
The vector velocities: $\boldsymbol{v}$ and $\boldsymbol{v_b}$ are of the surface and the boundary (I think these are spatially dependent). Annoyingly, I think also $\boldsymbol{r}$ is in place of $\boldsymbol{x}$.

*Note: I added the $n(\boldsymbol{x})$ into your $d\boldsymbol{A}$ terms, since the integral represents flux of a field through the surface, we are measuring the *component* (dot product) of the field aligning with the normal. This (unit normal) is scaled by the volume element in the integrand.*

But, with the given definitions $\color{red}{(red)}$, calculating the left hand sides gives:
$$(\star1) = \bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial_t}c(\boldsymbol{x})+[\nabla\cdot c(\boldsymbol{x})]\boldsymbol{v}(\boldsymbol{x})\bigg)\cdot \boldsymbol{n}(\boldsymbol{x})d\Sigma = \color{purple}{[\nabla\cdot c(\boldsymbol{x})]\boldsymbol{v}(\boldsymbol{x})\cdot \boldsymbol{n}(\boldsymbol{x})d\Sigma}$$
and
$$(\star2) = \color{purple}{-[\boldsymbol{v_b}(\boldsymbol{x})\times c(\boldsymbol{x})]\cdot \boldsymbol{n}(\boldsymbol{x})ds}.$$

---

The RHS's differ by one term (one zeroes out) and the dot term is left. This raises a question of how to take dot and cross product with a vector field and a scalar field (do we reduce to multiplication?). If this is the case, then by your observation with $v_b=0$ then the only surviving term would be:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\Sigma(t)}c(\boldsymbol{x})d\Sigma = \int_{\Sigma(t)}[\nabla\cdot c(\boldsymbol{x})]\boldsymbol{v}(\boldsymbol{x})\cdot \boldsymbol{n}(\boldsymbol{x})d\Sigma$$

---

Comment: I see the point , meaning that for a 2d surface in 3d space one ends up with an additional term , which indeed should be related to the divergence of the scalar normal to the surface velocity. I see many works defining this term in relation to curvature. Any idea how to relate the two?

Comment: So I am still skeptical of the correctness of the application of this formula (due to $c(\boldsymbol{x})$ and $\boldsymbol{n}(\boldsymbol{x})$ having different coordinate lengths, how to reconcile this? How are you motivating $c$?

Comment: As for your comment, you want to relate this potentially nonzero term to curvature of the surface?

Comment: A kind of curvature term is necessary in this problem. The formulation looks quite complicated. It also requires the notion of material “normal-to-the-surface” derivative. I good discuss I found is here https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-fluid-mechanics/article/transport-relations-for-surface-integrals-arising-in-the-formulation-of-balance-laws-for-evolving-fluid-interfaces/C32A9A84068352B54F11BF36B98E366C

Comment: The normal derivative of the scalar field would look like $\nabla_{\boldsymbol{n}(\boldsymbol{x})}c(\boldsymbol{x}) := \boldsymbol{n}^i(\boldsymbol{x})\partial_i c(\boldsymbol{x})$, summ. conv. applied.

Comment: Conditionally setting $c(\boldsymbol{x}) \leftrightarrow c(\boldsymbol{x})(1,1,1)$ for example, we could continue writing: $[\nabla\cdot c(\boldsymbol{x})]\boldsymbol{v}(\boldsymbol{x})\cdot\boldsymbol{n}(\boldsymbol{x}) = \bigg(\sum\limits_{i=1}^3\partial_ic(x)\bigg)\bigg(\sum\limits_{j=1}^3 v^j(\boldsymbol{x})n^j(\boldsymbol{x})\bigg) = \sum\limits_{i,j=1}^3 \bigg(v^j(x)n^j(x)\partial_ic(x)\bigg)$, which is oddly reminiscent to $\nabla_{n(x)}c(x) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^3n^i(x)\partial_ic(x)$...